# how to close 2 model in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am working on reactJs. I tried to generate user's gallery when user click on its avatar.I am using react-grid-gallery package for this.I uses semantic ui react for desiging.My code is:

```
<Modal trigger={<Image
        src={data.profile_photo}
        alt={data.name}
        size="massive"
        avatar

      />}
      style={ { height: "90%" } }>

        <Modal.Content >

          <Modal.Description>

          <Gallery images={Images} enableImageSelection='false'  isOpen={true} showLightboxThumbnails='true' rowHeight='120'/>
          </Modal.Description>
        </Modal.Content>
      </Modal>
```

Here `Images` is array of images which i already generated.Its works well and it generate slider.My question is this when i close slider still modal open.Basically there are two modal one for gallery and another is semantic.I want when i close Gallery Modal it should close semantic modal as well.how can i do it?? i tried to do by setting modelopen state but it not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lightboxWillClose` to toggle modal's `open`.
It would be something like this:

```
state = { modalOpen: false }

handleModalClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen = false })

handleModalOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen = true })

<Modal 
      open = {this.state.modalOpen}
      trigger={<Image
           onClick = {this.handleModalOpen}
           src={data.profile_photo}
           alt={data.name}
           size="massive"
           avatar 
          />}
      style={ { height: "90%" } }>

  <Modal.Content >
      <Modal.Description>
         <Gallery 
            images={Images} 
            enableImageSelection='false'  
            isOpen={true} 
            showLightboxThumbnails='true' 
            rowHeight='120'
            lightboxWillClose={this.handleModalClose}
           />
      </Modal.Description>
  </Modal.Content>
</Modal>
```

I haven't tested it so you might have to tweak it a little bit. But you get the idea.